# probability, depedence => uncorrelated?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

One quick question. Two random variables are dependent, so it must be uncorrelated?

Also for the terminalogy, does the term "uncorrelated" means two random variables have a corvariance factor of 0?

note corvairance factor= Cov(X,Y)/sqrt(Var(X)*Var(Y))?

Comment: Do you mean if they are dependent then it must be correlated?

Comment: If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, then they **could** be uncorrelated (but "usually" are not uncorrelated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, uncorrelated means that their covariance is zero.

Furthermore, if two random variables are independent, then they are indeed uncorrelated.
However, if they are uncorrelated, that does not mean that they are independent.

i would advise reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated

Comment: just to clarify, the fact that uncorrelated doesn't imply independence, is the same as saying that dependence doesnt imply correlation. Which is the question you asked.

Comment: but two random variable are "dependent" have nothing to do with the fact that they must be uncorrelated?